# What is the purpose or advanges of keeping a copy of readfds when using select()?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, select

TL;DR; Is it always necessary or recommended or is there any advantage on copying the select readfds fd_set over a "working" fd_set? What happens when using writefds and exceptfds?

This is my first question so apologies if this has been answered already but I tried to search as much as I could.

I am learning how to code with Unix C sockets API (specifically on GNU/Linux), and I have found many ways to deal with sockets using select() for sync I/O multiplexing.

Until now I only used the readfds fd_set of the select() function, many tutorials omits the other 2 sets, however the example of "man select_tut" gives me hints of ways to also use writefds, therefore I am experimenting with this set as well.

Beej's Guide example server (http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/examples/selectserver.c) shows the usage of a "master" fd_set.

However for instance, "man select_tut" only uses the 3 canonical fd_sets.

Imho, as long as you FD_ZERO the sets before select(), it will add the active descriptors on each set... so I don't see much point on keeping a second copy of the fd_sets out of the "select loop".

Thoughts?

Comment: The advantage may be that you do a (probably optimized) memory copy, instead of an (possible) slow loop.

Comment: Understand, but, since I still have to loop over the file descriptors to handle the active ones, I don't see the need of another copy of the fd_sets... unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Imho, as long as you FD_ZERO the sets before select(), it will add the
>   active descriptors on each set...

That's not true.

When you call `select` you need to specify exactly the descriptors you are interested in. After it returns, **it partially clears the sets**, i.e. only the descriptors that were "interesting" on that iteration are still set. That's why you need to reinitialize the sets.

The standard page spells it clearly:

> Upon successful completion, the `pselect()` or `select()` function **shall
>   modify the objects pointed to by the readfds, writefds, and errorfds**
>   arguments to indicate which file descriptors are ready for reading,
>   ready for writing, or have an error condition pending, respectively,
>   and shall return the total number of ready descriptors in all the
>   output sets.

Comment: Ok, now I think I understand it better. Therefore, whenever I get a new connection, I add that connection to my "interesting_fd_set" (I have been doing this upon accept() then FD_SET(...)", then, before each select() I should FD_ZERO(...) the sets I want to monitor (with select()) and copy the "interesting_fd_set" over read_fd_set, write_fd_set and/or except_fd_set, then select() will monitor those for activity and I shall handle them with each respective FD_ISSET(...), right?

Comment: @elmorti You don't need to `FD_ZERO` anything inside the main loop. When you `accept` you add the `fd` to persistent set (called `master` in your question) and every time before `select` you just assign that to your `read_fds`.

Comment: Indeed you are right, doesn't make sense to FD_ZERO and then memcpy the persisten set over. Thanks a lot for the clarification!